# What icon pack/theme is this?

Tags: themes, icon-themes

I want to know which theme & which icon pack is used in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Specifically? Do you want to move the panel to the bottom?

Comment: Using unity tweak tool i can move the panel to the bottom, i want to know which theme and which icon pack used by user

Comment: I Think It's [paper theme](https://snwh.org/paper).

Comment: @ImranShaikh Where did you get this screenshot from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is Flatabulous theme and Ultra-Flat icon pack.

Maybe this step-by-step installation can help:

1. Install tweak tools for your desktop environments

   Install Unity Tweak Tool for Unity

   ```
   sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
   ```

   **or**

   Install Gnome Tweak Tool for GNOME

   ```
   sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool
   ```
2. Install [Flatabulous](https://github.com/anmoljagetia/Flatabulous) theme

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install flatabulous-theme
   ```
3. Install Ultra flat Icon pack

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/icons
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install ultra-flat-icons
   ```
4. Change Theme and Icon Pack with tweak tools

   Screenshoots for `unity-tweak-tool`

   **Theme**

   [image: theme1]

   [image: theme2]

   **Icon**

   [image: icon1]

   [image: icon2]

   Sorry, I only have Unity, so there are no `gnome-tweak-tool` screenshoots.

   This my desktop appearance:

   [image: my desktop]

Comment: @ImranShaikh If you think this answer _answers_ your question, accept it. That works as 'thank you'

Comment: As an addition, I want to mention the name of the Font used. It is "Roboto"

Comment: Very nice desktop wallpaper @Anwar can you send me the where i can find type of wallpaper...

Comment: No, I don't know @ImranShaikh. Maybe the answerer can give it to us :)

Comment: I got the image from [here](http://wallpapersonthe.net/17266-desert-clouds-sun-artwork/)

Comment: Can anyone suggest me some link where can i find some cool wallpaper for my Ubuntu desktop.